Did this program exist?
The name is "pic view" or "picview" the OS is Machintosh (8 or 9, I don't recognize it), but searching on google I cannot find it, did anyone know more? The screenshot is from movie Striking Poses


Anything you find in a movie is likely to be pure fiction. It's hard to be sure from the fuzzy picture, but it looks to me like the actual images have higher resolution than the rest of the screen, so they were likely added in post-production.

As with your previous question, these are better suited for [movies.se]. We can only give positive answers, but they can give negative answers too (since they can look into the production process).

In addition to Dave's notes regarding resolution differences, it would not make any sense at all for a Mac application of that vintage to have big words for functions with no icons - Rename, Save, Delete, Quit. Even Windows applications tend to better than that.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact there was a time (say 1990s) when any amateur programmer could write a small, ugly program without following any particular aesthetic or guidelines, and if it was useful and free, people would start using and sharing it. Of course that doesn't mean that this is one of them - certainly looks like a mock-up to me.
